# codeigniter check box value

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

hello everyone I just started working with codeigniter and php. I am making a simple survey type website whit check-boxes the questions are going to be multiple choice and the results will be stored in a database if a check-box is checked. my question is how would I go about of doing that.here is my form and thanks for everyone help in advance.

**view**

```
<?php foreach($survay_data as $survay):?> 
    <ul>
        <li><h1><?php echo $survay->Question;?></h1></li> 
        <li><?php echo $survay->qA; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="qA"></li>
        <li><?php echo $survay->qB; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="qB"></li>
        <li><?php echo $survay->qC; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="qC"></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <input type="textarea" value='a' name="comment">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </ul>
```

**controller**

```
<?php
    class Survay extends CI_Model{

        function dosurvay($arrData){

            $this->db->select('QID, Question, qA, qB, qC');
            $this->db->from('tblquestions');
            $this->db->where('Question', $arrData['Question']);
            $this->db->where('qA', $arrData['qA']);
            $this->db->where('qB', $arrData['qB']);
            $this->db->where('qC', $arrData['qC']);
            $this -> db -> limit(1);

            $query = $this -> db -> get();

            if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
            {
                return $query->result();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**model**

```
<?php
class Survaycontroller extends CI_Controller{
   // 'QID, Question, qA, qB, qC'

    function index()
    {

            $arrData = array();
            $arrData["qA"] = $this->input->post("qA");
            $arrData["qB"] = $this->input->post("qB");
            $arrData["qC"] = $this->input->post("qC");
            $arrData["Question"] = $this->input->post("Question");

            $this->load->model('survay');

            $survay_data = $this->survay->dosurvay($arrData);

            $viewData['survay_data'] = $survay_data;

            $this->load->view('survay_view', $viewData);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can we possibly see what you've tried in the controller or model also? Please read these manuals: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html. They should get you started right.

Comment: i edited my post and added a controller and the model code. i did look at the user guide of codeigniter it helped me out tru maust of this project but cant figure out how to return check box values.

Comment: Depending on where the problem lies. If you want to do a select, I doubt how you would come up with a result with all those where's Just pick the question using the question id. If you intend to insert the answer into the db instead, create an insert statement. The problem is in your model and those strange square brackets. Do you want to INSERT or SELECT Questions? I've made comments on how to insert even with array in my answer below. See if that helps

Comment: all i want is to insert the answers in to the database tables

Comment: Done, I've provided a new answer that would select and insert to database. Test it. I haven't had the time to but it should get your on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This should do what you want. Based on our Chat on Stackover, the answer has been provided for you. Your question is not as clear as the request you made on the chat. Find below the codes that can fix your issue**

## BASIC USE OF CODEIGNITER:

I'm providing this codes just for you to reduce the amount of comments we have going.
It's certain you are pretty new to Codeigniter. I can only help as I can.

**Step 1: THE DATABASE**

> Create the database table "tblquestions". fields should be QID, qA, qB and qC. populate the fields with records like up to 43 if you have that much. As little a 5 records should do.

**Step 2: THE MODEL**

```
<?php

class Survay extends CI_Model {

    function dosurvay($question_id = null) {

        $this->db->select('QID, Question, qA, qB, qC');
        $this->db->from('tblquestions');
        if ($question_id) {
            $this->db->where('QID', $question_id);
        }
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 function addsurvay($arrData) {

    $this->db->insert('tblanswers', $arrData);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
?>
```

**Step 3: THE CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

class Survaycontroller extends CI_Controller {

    // 'QID, Question, qA, qB, qC'
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('survay');
    }

    function index() {
        //This should select the survey question
        $data = array();
        $question_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data[survay_data] = $this->survay->dosurvay($question_id);
        $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);
    }

    function addanswer() {
        //The answer is submitted to this...
        $arrData = array();
        $userid = null;
        if ($this->session->userdata("userid")) {
            $userid = $this->session->userdata("userid");
        }
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $arrData["answerid"] = $this->input->post("QID");
            $arrData["questionid"] = $this->input->post("qA");
            if ($this->input->post("qA")) {
                $arrData["answerA"] = $this->input->post("qA");
            }
            if ($this->input->post("qB")) {
                $arrData["answerB"] = $this->input->post("qB");
            }
            if ($this->input->post("qC")) {
                $arrData["answerC"] = $this->input->post("qC");
            }
            $arrData["userid"] = $userid;
        }
        $viewData[survay_data_id] = $this->survay->addsurvay($arrData); //Get the ID of the answer stored
        $this->load->view('survay_view', $viewData);
    }

}
?>
```

**Step 4: THE VIEW**

```
<?php if(isset($survay_data)) : ?>
<form action="http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/addanswer/" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
   <?php foreach ($survay_data as $survay): ?> 
        <ul>
            <li><h1><?php echo $survay->Question; ?></h1></li> 
            <li><?php echo $survay->qA; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qA" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
            <li><?php echo $survay->qB; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qB" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
            <li><?php echo $survay->qC; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qC" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" name="QID" value="<?php echo $survay->QID; ?>"></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="btn" value="Answer"></li>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

TEST IT:

```
http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/index/2
```

to retrieve question number 2

Now this is sure to work. Replace everything you already have. Let me know if these new sets of codes replace the ones I have above more efficiently.

Comment: your help is very much appreciated Steward i tried your code and i am getting couple of errors.

Comment: here are the errors

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Survaycontroller::index()

Filename: controllers/survaycontroller.php

Line Number: 7
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: QID

Filename: controllers/survaycontroller.php

Line Number: 11
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/survay_view.php

Line Number: 1

Comment: Okay, I expected you to provide the question id like this: http://localhost/subsite/controller/index/5 where 5 is the question id from QID. That would be used to filter the database for the right question to display. Check my edit and retry providing an id you are aware exists in your db. That would help you test things.

Comment: this might sound stupid but i am a bit lost can u explain more tnx

Comment: Okay, let me have the url starting with http:// used to open the page that should display the question and one id from your database corresponding to a question want to display.

Comment: i added the link that is shown above it displays the page but it still has few errors

Comment: It would be good to let me know the error in your comments so I can see how to debug the code faster. Try this: http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/index/43. The Question ID should be in segment(3)

Comment: the errors are gone i added the url as u said it only displays the http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/index/43' url on the web page and the question is not displayed

Comment: Did you provide a valid id? If you did and tablename is correct, etc try `print_r(  $data[survay_data] )` in controller/index to see if you have values. If you have data, then the problem would be in how it is used.

Comment: yeas the id is valid also the table name is correct to, i forgot to tell u i haven created a table that needs to store the check box values could that be a problem in someway ? when i tried to print out i received 2 error messages : A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant survay_data - assumed 'survay_data'

Filename: controllers/survaycontroller.php

Line Number: 9

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/survaycontroller.php

Line Number: 9 an the url is still displaying.

Comment: I've corrected two lines to fix that: `$data['survay_data'] = $this->survay->dosurvay($question_id);` and `$viewData['survay_data_id'] = $this->survay->addsurvay($arrData);`. Just put the quotes in the array keys. If you hadn't created the table where in the world are we trying to get the data from? Please create table, fill with values at least two rows. Take the id number from QID field and test before getting back. I can only help you fix this now, I'd be off in the new few minutes.

Comment: i already wasted enough of you time tnx so much for your help. good luck. i will try to solve this on my own for now tnx again.i have the question table but haven created the table where the answer will be stored

Comment: Took some time off. If you have the table having the questions. That's find for displaying the records. You've not told me what was returned from the print_r( $data['survay_data'] ). Please include the quotes. That could take us on the right part. I still have to figure if you have anything else in your code give you problems. Let me have the print_r. I think your request is achieveable.

Comment: hi Steward i placed the print_r( $data['survay_data'] ); at the end of index function it did not return anything only the URL was displayed. i have id_key is unused in the scope in the surveycontroller.

Comment: id_key is not used anywhere in my code. I guess that is coming from somewhere else in your code. You need to be able to retrieve data from your database first. If `print_r('survay_data']; exit;` is not returning any value. If you used this url `http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/index/43` and a question with `QID = 43` is in the database table `tblquestions` and object would be returned and passed to the at array. Using print_r, the array can be viewed. So you either have more codes messing up with the whole thing or doing something wrong here.

Comment: In addition to the above, Call this function and let's see what you get back. You can do this from the controller as test...   

`function dosurvay(43) {
        $this->db->select('QID, Question, qA, qB, qC');
        $this->db->from('tblquestions');
        $this->db->where('QID', $question_id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        print_r ($query->result() );
    }`   

Where 43 is the id of a record in your db corresponding to QID. Please note that Stackoverflow FAQ covers the fact that you have an idea of what you doing. We can't give you all codes here

Comment: the id_key is at this line of code  
foreach ($question_array as $id_key => $id_value) {
i eddied my code exactly as you showed me with your example what can  be the problem ?

Comment: $id_key is in controller function `addanswer()` calls `addsurvay()` in model. which would be used to add the answer to the database later. Now you want to retrieve questions and you should use `index()` to call  `dosurvay()`. In the controller, we are calling `index()` now. The targeted model function in `index()` is accessing `dosurvay()` and has nothing to do with `id_key` which is in a `addsurvay()`. You've probably mistyped and targeted the wrong function in controller (see above url). Please correct that and follow the additional comments above. Let me have the result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25208/discussion-between-steward-godwin-jornsen-and-edvinas-liutvaitis)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php foreach($survay_data as $survay):?> 
<ul>
<li><h1><?php echo $survay->Question;?></h1></li> 
<li><?php echo $survay->qA; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
<li><?php echo $survay->qB; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="<?php echo $survay->qB; ?>"></li>
<li><?php echo $survay->qC; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="<?php echo $survay->qC; ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<input type="textarea" value='a' name="comment">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</ul>
```

You need to put the data retrieved on the database as the value for the checkbox.. On your controller you can `var_dump($this->input->post())` to see what data has been submitted then you can manipulate it as you like.

**EXPANDED a LITTLE:**

In short you are trying to assign the values from the database to the value attr, which will be sent as the value when a user checks a checkbox.

on the form whether you are using a `form_open()` or a standard `<form>` tag type in the controller that will receive your data.

```
function dosurvay($arrData){

    // you're get survay things here


    if($this->input->post())// will execute only if a post happens
    {
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($this->input->post()); // just print out everything
       echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for your help tomexsans can u expand more on this i am a bit lost on this subject