# storing check box value in to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to code a simple survey application using codeigniter i have a check box for every answer and i want to store every answer i to a table on a database what i want to ask is how would i store all of this information on to a table i am new to coding world a simple solution will do. right now all i have is the view set up here it is:

```
<html>
 <body>

<?php form_open('survay'); ?>  
<?php foreach($survay_data as $survay):?> 
<ul>
    <li><h1><?php echo $survay->Question; ?></h1></li> 
    <li><?php echo $survay->qA; ?><input type="checkbox"  name = "q1" value = "qA"></li>
    <li><?php echo $survay->qB; ?><input type="checkbox"  name = "q2" value = "qB"></li>
    <li><?php echo $survay->qC; ?><input type="checkbox"  name = "q3" value = "qC"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<input type="textarea" value='a' name="comment">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's interesting that you got a vote up for this question even if you did not show any attempt to save those values

Comment: i asked for help and i receive help there is nothing interesting about that :)

Comment: I honestly have been looking at your code the last few questions and trying to determine what it is you're trying to do, with no success. Is this a multiple choice survey? If so does that code represent one question? It would be a lot easier to help if we knew what you were trying to accomplish because the way that code is laid out is not ideal for a multiple choice scenario to be honest.

Comment: yes it would be a multiple choice survey and yes the page would only display one question on the web page. well what i am trying to accomplish is basically have a one question survey displayed on the page. all the questions and multiple choice answers will be added from the database table and also when the survey is answered the result will be stored in a database and displayed on another page for admin to look at. in the future i would like to add pagination to the survey where the questions will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086172/827224

**This should do what you want. Based on our Chat on Stackover, the answer has been provided for you. Your question is not as clear as the request you made on the chat. Find below the codes that can fix your issue**

## BASIC USE OF CODEIGNITER:

I'm providing this codes just for you to reduce the amount of comments we have going.
It's certain you are pretty new to Codeigniter. I can only help as I can.

**Step 1: THE DATABASE**

> Create the database table "tblquestions". fields should be QID, qA, qB and qC. populate the fields with records like up to 43 if you have that much. As little a 5 records should do.

**Step 2: THE MODEL**

```
<?php

class Survay extends CI_Model {

    function dosurvay($question_id = null) {

        $this->db->select('QID, Question, qA, qB, qC');
        $this->db->from('tblquestions');
        if ($question_id) {
            $this->db->where('QID', $question_id);
        }
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 function addsurvay($arrData) {

    $this->db->insert('tblanswers', $arrData);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
?>
```

**Step 3: THE CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

class Survaycontroller extends CI_Controller {

    // 'QID, Question, qA, qB, qC'
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('survay');
    }

    function index() {
        //This should select the survey question
        $data = array();
        $question_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data[survay_data] = $this->survay->dosurvay($question_id);
        $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);
    }

    function addanswer() {
        //The answer is submitted to this...
        $arrData = array();
        $userid = null;
        if ($this->session->userdata("userid")) {
            $userid = $this->session->userdata("userid");
        }
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $arrData["answerid"] = $this->input->post("QID");
            $arrData["questionid"] = $this->input->post("qA");
            if ($this->input->post("qA")) {
                $arrData["answerA"] = $this->input->post("qA");
            }
            if ($this->input->post("qB")) {
                $arrData["answerB"] = $this->input->post("qB");
            }
            if ($this->input->post("qC")) {
                $arrData["answerC"] = $this->input->post("qC");
            }
            $arrData["userid"] = $userid;
        }
        $viewData[survay_data_id] = $this->survay->addsurvay($arrData); //Get the ID of the answer stored
        $this->load->view('survay_view', $viewData);
    }

}
?>
```

**Step 4: THE VIEW**

```
<?php if(isset($survay_data)) : ?>
<form action="http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/addanswer/" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
   <?php foreach ($survay_data as $survay): ?> 
        <ul>
            <li><h1><?php echo $survay->Question; ?></h1></li> 
            <li><?php echo $survay->qA; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qA" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
            <li><?php echo $survay->qB; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qB" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
            <li><?php echo $survay->qC; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qC" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" name="QID" value="<?php echo $survay->QID; ?>"></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="btn" value="Answer"></li>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

TEST IT:

```
http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/index/2
```

to retrieve question number 2

Now this is sure to work. Replace everything you already have. Let me know if these new sets of codes replace the ones I have above more efficiently.